# Grep .html Syntax

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm very new to bash so I apologize if this is a dumb question.

I'm trying to write a script that takes a file and tests to see if it ends in html. Here is my code:

```
echo tester.html | grep -E '[^ ]*[.html]'
```

Yet it echos every input I give it, how do I fix it?

Comment: The file, or the name of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo tester.html | grep -q '\.html$' && echo "MATCH" || echo >&2 "NO MATCH"
```

or in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
x=tester.html
[[ $x == *html ]] && echo "MATCH" || echo >&2 "NO MATCH"
```

`&&` & `||` boolean syntax is a shorcut for `if condition; then something; else something_else; fi`, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

**NOTE**
 - using `[]` in a [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) means *character class* (a set of characters)

Comment: Added explanations in my post =)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it with the help of sputnick.

Here it is:

```
echo tester.html | grep -E *html
```

and this works,

thanks all.

Comment: If you want to match _end of line_, you should use `$` special character : this means _end of line_ in regex. Moreover, no need _extented regex_ : `-E`. And to finish, you should use quotes around the regex.